# Failed fetch new data from cloud after submit (react native & redux toolkit )

Tags: react-native, expo, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to submit new data to cloud firestore and it works good. but when is done and go back to main screen (todoList) i've got this error

[image]

below some code from store, slice and view for render data

this the slice (todoSlice)

```
// FOR fetch data from cloud firestore
export const fetchTodos = createAsyncThunk('fetchTodos', async () => {
    try {
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "todos"))
        const dataTodos = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
            id: doc.id,
            ...doc.data()
        }))
        //console.log("check refs", dataTodos);
        return dataTodos
    } catch (error) {
        return alert(error.message)
    }
})
```

```
// FOR addDoc to collection cloud firestore
export const addTodoLists = createAsyncThunk('addTodoLists', async (data) => {
    try {
        const addTodoRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "todos"), data)
        const newTodo = { id: addTodoRef.id, data }
        return newTodo
    } catch (error) {
        return alert(error.message)
    }
})
```

```
const todoSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'todos',
    initialState: {
        data: [],
        isLoading:false,
        error: false
    },
    extraReducers(builder) {
        builder
            .addCase(fetchTodos.pending, (state, action) => {
                state.isLoading = true
            })
            .addCase(fetchTodos.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.isLoading=false
                state.data = action.payload
            })
            .addCase(fetchTodos.rejected, (state, action) => {
                state.isLoading = false
                state.error = true
            })
            .addCase(addTodoLists.pending,(state,action) => {
                state.isLoading = true
            })
            .addCase(addTodoLists.fulfilled,(state,action) => {
                state.isLoading = false
                state.data  = action.payload
            })
            .addCase(addTodoLists.rejected,(state,action) => {
                state.isLoading = false
                state.error = true
            })
    }
})

export default todoSlice.reducer
```

this the store (store.js)

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import todoReducer from "../slice/todoSlice";

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        todo: todoReducer
    }
})

export default store
```

and this todoList (todoList.js)

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchTodos } from '../redux/slice/todoSlice';

const TodoList = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const todos = useSelector(state => state.todo.data)
    console.log("check state ", todos);

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchTodos())
    }, [])

    return (
        <View>
            {todos && todos.map((item) => {
                return(
                    <View key={item.id}>
                        <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                    </View>
                )
            })}
        </View>
    )
}

export default TodoList
```